# In Ember.js how do you extend a component and trigger an action on did-insert?

Tags: ember.js

Our project is currently using Ember 3.12 and we are trying to upgrade to using Ember 3.20, but we are having an issue with extending an ember-power-select component (which now uses Glimmer components). In our extended component we need to call a method when the component is inserted and have access to component element, which we did using didInsertElement in Ember 3.12, but we now need to use a did-insert modifier. However, when we create a template file of our own which contains an element which triggers the did-insert modifier the power-select element is not displayed (because our template file has replaced it). I would rather not copy the entire contents of the power-select.hbs file into our own file and wrap it in a div that contains the did-insert modifier so that we can get access the component element in the action. Is there a pattern for this situation? Like templates can now be extended or there is another way to trigger an action when the component is inserted (and still get access to the component's element)?

Comment: Same exact issue, same exact addon :), just I am moving to 3.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to *not* extend a component in Ember Octance by extending from it's JavaScript class. Instead invoke the component in the template of the wrapping component:

```
{{! app/component/wrapper-around-ember-power-select.hbs }}

<PowerSelect
  {{! passthrough all arguments you want to support }}
  @selected={{@selected}}
  @options={{@options}}
  @onChange={{@onChange}}
  
  {{! register your own modifier }}
  {{did-insert this.onEmberPowerSelectInsertIntoDom}}

  {{! set some HTML attributes }}
  class="foo"
/>
```

```js
// app/component/wrapper-around-ember-power-select.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class WrapperAroundEmberPowerSelectComponent extends Component {
  @action
  onEmberPowerSelectInsertIntoDom(element) {
    // do something with the element
  }
}
```

Extending the component in this way has the benefit of only using its public API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems to be what we will need to do. Lots of arguments to add! I think it's a shame we have lost the ability to extend a component like before. I don't remember the guides covering this scenario, maybe I have just forgotten.

Comment: For some reason the did-insert action isn't triggered in the PowerSelect so I had to have a wrapping div that has the did-insert modifier on it instead.

Comment: Maybe Ember Power Select does not apply `...attributes` to any argument? You can also use `{{did-insert}}` helper provided by ember-render-helpers if only interested in lifecycle but not in an element. As it's an helper you don't need to create another element just to use it.